# Special price not showing on category page

Tags: magento, error-handling

I have added special price for the products. it's showing special price on product detail page but not showing on the category page. if I call specialprice on list.phtml than it show only 0. I think need to make some changes in list.php .

code are below:-
 in list.php my function is

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }

            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }



        }


        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

list.phtml

```
  <?php
        $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

            <?php // Grid Mode ?>

            <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
            <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
            <div class="products-grid">
                <div class="row">
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
                $id_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
                        //$count_input_qty++;
                        $now = date("Y-m-d");
                        $newsFrom = substr($_product->getData('news_from_date'), 0, 10);
                        $newsTo = substr($_product->getData('news_to_date'), 0, 10);

                        $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
                        //echo $specialprice . '-hau<br/>';
                        $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice();
                        if ($specialprice == '') {
                            $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
                            $discounted_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice(
                                Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($store_id),
                                Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)->getWebsiteId(),
                                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
                                $_product->getId());
                            $specialprice = $discounted_price;

                        }
            ?>
                <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>

                <?php endif ?>

                        <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 respl-item">
                        <div class="item-inner">
                            <div class="w-image-box">   
                                <div class="item-image">
                                    <!--SHOW 2 IMAGE FOR PRODUCTS-->
                                        <?php $_media = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() ?>

                                        <?php $count_item=0; $check_img=0;?>

                                        <?php $check_img = count($_media);?>

                                    <a class="<?php if ($check_img >= 2) echo $this->__('rspl-image');?>" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                                        <img class="first_image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(270); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /> 

                                        <?php if ($check_img >= 2): ?>
                                            <?php 
                                            $flag=0;
                                            foreach($_media as $_img): ?>
                                                    <?php $count_item++;?>
                                                    <?php if ($_img->getFile() == $_product->getSmallImage()){
                                                        if($count_item==$check_img){
                                                            $flag = 0;
                                                        }else{
                                                            $flag = 1;
                                                        }
                                                        continue;
                                                    }  ?>
                                                    <?php if($flag==1) { ?>
                                                    <img class="last_image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_img->getFile())->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(270,270); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" />
                                                    <?php  break; }?>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            <?php 
                                                if($flag==0){
                                                    foreach($_media as $_img){ ?>
                                                     <img class="last_image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_img->getFile())->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(270,270); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" />
                                                <?php break; }
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        <?php endif?>
                                    <!--END SHOW 2 IMAGE FOR PRODUCTS-->   
                                    </a>



                                </div>
                                <?php if ($newsFrom != "" && $now >= $newsFrom && ($now <= $newsTo || $newsTo == "")) { ?>
                                    <div class="new-product">
                                            <?php echo $this->__('New'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }?>
                                <?php if ($specialprice) { ?>
                                    <div class='sale-item'>
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Sale'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }?>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-info">
                                <div class="item-title ">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                                    <?php if( strlen($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) > 100 ){
                                         echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 100);
                                    } else {
                                        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                                    }?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-review">
                                    <?php  echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true); ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="item-price">
                                    <?php // echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                                </div>
                                <!--
                                <div class="item-desc">
                                    <?php 
                                        echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description'), 0, 70);
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                -->
                                <div class="item-addto-wrap">
                                    <div class="button-action item-addcart">
                                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <a class="button btn-cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($id_product) ?>')">
                                            <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                        <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                                            <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?> </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <?php endif; ?> 

                                        <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>
                                            <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                                <?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                            </a>
                                        <?php endif;?>

                                        <?php if ( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() ) : ?>
                                            <a class="link-wishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>">
                                                <?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
                                            </a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>


                                    </div>
                                </div>              
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>

                <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

suggest me , what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Re-index `"Category Products"` even if the `Status = Ready` & `Update Required =  NO`

Answer (score 0):

As I remember on product view pages all prices collected on the fly. But on pages with many products (grid/list) prices get from the database.
It means that the most probably your code doesn't have issues. There is a problem in your database. Try to reindex, reSave, check the values in the database.

Also try to disable any modules which can affect on calculating price process and then reindex and reSave. Turn on default theme in system / design.

Hope it will be helpful.